# Render partial from arbitrary class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to be able to do this from a view:

```
<%= my_component.render %>
```

Where `my_component` is an instance of the following:

```
class RandomComponent

  def render
    renderer.render(partial: 'components/random_component', object: self)
  end

  def renderer
    # ???
  end
end
```

I've tried a variety of things in the `renderer` method - a call to `ActionView::PartialRenderer.new`, an instance of a class that includes `ApplicationHelper`, and an instance of a class that includes `ActionView::Helpers`, etc.

What am I missing? Is there a way to do this without passing around a reference to the current view instance? I'm not a fan of doing `<%= my_component.render(self) %>` everywhere.